# IE8 layout broken - IE7 mode correct

Tags: html, css, css-float

after 3-4 hours of searching with IE's "dev tools", I can't understand why.

This code: https://tinker.io/b2c10 produces the layout correctly in IE7 mode, Chrome, Firefox. In IE8 Standards mode, here's the result when you make the viewport smaller:

[image: broken layout in IE8]

And here is how the layout should be / is in all other browsers (IE7 included):

[image: correct layout]

Needless to say I experimented with all including:

- reducing the max-width of the img
- removing the Who's Who part with the display:inline-block's
- removing the image completely from the middle column...

Comment: If you downvote please care to comment so I can improve the question.

Comment: Does the HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?  IE hates invalid code.

Comment: I don't have control of the HTML as it's CMS-produced (Sharepoint 2007..)

Comment: IE does not care where the HTML came from.  If it's invalid, you're likely going to have issues.

Comment: (I didn't downvote but have a likely cause) Your Tinker example code seems to be irrelevant to this question because it shows something completely different. **Or** it may be that it has a lot of other *garbage* which makes it hard for use to tweak it. Produce example code that we can actually work with. People may think that your example code may as well be tricky advertising hence the downvoting? Just guessing here.

Comment: I am actually trying to delete my question as I found the answer.. but there is no such way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there was a problem in how Sharepoint was converting my source html making it not valid...

Answer (score 0):

In a not so clean way you can start by setting min-width on the divs with that content. That will also help to keep it from overlapping as it scales down.  Also I think you might want to switch to spans for the div width.  I feel like I am preaching Scaffolding to a lot of people but it really does help keep things scaling nicely.

```
.ms-WPBody {padding:0;overflow:visible;min-width:190px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8LEE/

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 0):

p wich is block by default, with div using float: right, padding instead of margin....not sure how this is working, you need to improve your css a bit dude. I sugest you review it all.